# From integer to bits and back again

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert an integer value to its bit expression and convert parts of that again to integer [(as per this blogpost, for context)](https://blog.ip2location.com/knowledge-base/convert-ip2location-csv-data-into-ip-ranges-or-cidr/).

Transforming integers to bits does seem to work, but I'm missing something when transforming the values back into the initial integer.

```
'intToBase2' <- function(x){
  x %>% 
    intToBits() %>%
    rev %>%
    as.character() %>%
    {sapply(strsplit(., "", fixed = TRUE), '[', 2)} %>%
    paste0(.,collapse = '')
}
val <- 1855928457
intToBase2(val) # does seem to return the correct bit expression, as expected
```

However, if I try to reverse the same logic, something gets lost somewhere:

```
val %>%
  intToBase2 %>%               # Get expression in bits
  {strsplit(.,'')[[1]]} %>%    # split
  sprintf('0%s',.) %>%         # add leading zeros
  rev %>%                      # reverse order
  as.raw %>%                   # expression to raw
  readBin(.,what='integer')

R> [1] 16777217
```

What am I missing? I assume some of the steps I did are incorrect.

Comment: ``packBits`` seems to work instead of ``readBin``, didn't need to delete the comment, thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function reverses yours, and is vectorized:

```r
base2ToInt <- function(string)
{
  sapply(strsplit(string, ""), function(x) sum(rev(+(x == "1")) * 2^(seq(x)-1)))
}
```

So you can do

```
base2ToInt(c("1", "0", "10", "11111111"))
#> [1]   1   0   2 255
```

and

```
base2ToInt(intToBase2(val))
#> [1] 1855928457
> base2ToInt(intToBase2(val)) == val
#> [1] TRUE
```

It works by splitting the string(s) into characters, so each string becomes a vector of "1"s and "0"s. These are converted to numeric values, then reversed, then multiplied by a sequence of powers of 2 of the same length. This is summed to give an answer for each string.

It's a bit "code golf", but bit manipulation often is...